# Undefined offset while printing multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array in PHP which looks like this

```
$names_of_tragedies=array(
      $row["Character_code"]=>array(
         ($another_counter)=>$temp_string)
                          )
```

I am creating an array called `$names_of_tragedies.`

It has several subsets or sub-arrays, with each sub-array being named `$row["Character_code"]` and the `"Character_Code"` is different for each sub-array.

Each of these sub-arrays has another array within, with the header field being called `$another_counter`. `$another_counter` is a numerical value, so it ranges from 1 to a fixed number.

I am entering the data correctly. I have checked it. The problem is with printing it.

Whereas I can access every sub-array `$row["Character_code"]`, I can access only the final sub-sub-array `$another_counter`.

For e.g., if I have a sub-array where `$row["Character_code"]='Prometheus'` and `'Prometheus'` has only one sub-sub-array [1] whose value is 'APB', I can print it, using

```
echo $names_of_tragedies[$row["Character_code"]][$another_counter];
```

The problem occurs when a sub-sub-array has multiple values.

For e.g., if I have a sub-array where `$row["Character_code"]='Antigone'` and `'Antigone'` has 5 sub-sub-arrays **[1],[2],[3],[4] and [5]** whose value is
**[1]='ASAT',[2]='SANTIGONE',[3]='SOTK',[4]='SOAC' and [5]='EPW'**,

then creating a loop where the value of the variable `$another_counter` changes from 1 to 5, and using `$row["Character_code"]='Antigone`,

```
echo $names_of_tragedies[$row["Character_code"]][$another_counter];
```

only successfully returns the value of EPW. For every other occasion when **$another_counter=1,2,3 or 4**,

it says

> Undefined offset: 1 or Undefined offset: 2 or Undefined offset: 3 or
>   Undefined offset: 4

. It is only when I reach the final value, 5, that it displays the data, 'EPW'.

Somehow the counter seems to be set to the last or only value. How do I print the earlier sub-sub-arrays?

Comment: it may help to show us the print_r output of your array

Comment: You must use isset or array_key_exists to avoid this.

Comment: Try starting at 0 rather than 1. Maybe...

Comment: The code you have shown where you fill this array, seems to overwrite the array under the key `$row["Character_code"]` every single time, instead of actually _adding_ items to it.

Comment: @chris-lear Starting at 0 does not help. It shows undefined offset:0 even for the ones with just a single $another_counter.

Comment: Those four initial lines should probably rather be something like this: `$names_of_tragedies[$row["Character_code"]][$another_counter] = $temp_string;`

Comment: @lovelace print_r for 'Antigone' produces this. Array ( [Antigone] => Array ( [5] => EPW ) )  Am I entering the data incorrectly as misorude says?

Comment: @misorude You were right. I was entering the data incorrectly. I pasted your corrected code. That solved it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have shown where you fill this array, seems to *overwrite* the array under the key `$row["Character_code"]` every single time, instead of actually *adding* items to it.

Those four initial lines should probably rather be something like this:

```
$names_of_tragedies[$row["Character_code"]][$another_counter] = $temp_string;
```

That will add all the `$temp_string`s to the array that is `$names_of_tragedies[$row["Character_code"]]`, using `$another_counter` as the key for each item.